# Show all errors with formly

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

How can I show all validation errors on submit with formly?

form

```
<formly-form model="vm.model" fields="vm.fields" form="vm.form">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="submit()">Save changes</button>
</formly-form>
```

controller

```
$scope.submit = function () {
  if (!$scope.form.$valid) {
    $scope.form.$setUntouched();
  }
};
```

I find just form.$setUntouched() method in angular.js to hide errors.

Comment: no idea how to touch all fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Config:

```
app.run(function(formlyConfig) {
    formlyConfig.extras.errorExistsAndShouldBeVisibleExpression = 'fc.$touched || form.$submitted';
});
```

Controller:

```
$scope.submit = function () {
  $scope.form.$submitted = true;
  if ($scope.form.$valid) {
    // Do submit
  }
};
```